# Change language of Adobe Flash CS6

Tags: adobe, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I have just installed trial version of Adobe Flash CS6 using Adobe's own installer. It installed the software automatically in my local language. I want to change the language of the application to English so it will be easier to follow English tutorials. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No". You should uninstall and select proper language during installation.